# how can i fix this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Showing C:/Sites/Edeal/app/views/orders/sales.html.erb where line #17 raised:

undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #17):
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<tr>
     <td><%= image_tag order.listing.image.url(:thumb) %></td>
     <td><%= order.listing.name %></td>

     <td ><%= number_to_currency(order.listing.price,:unit => "UGX") %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your orders does not have a listing. You can guard against the error like this:

```
<% if order.listing %>
  <td><%= image_tag order.listing.image.url(:thumb) %></td>
  <td><%= order.listing.name %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_currency(order.listing.price,:unit => "UGX") %></td>
<% else %>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
<% end %>
```